# Oracle - filtering Cartesian coordinate

Tags: sql, oracle, cartesian-product

I have a `mating_history` table:

```
id    cage_id   code    event_date                    animal_id
---------------------------------------------------------------
100   4163      FA      03-Aug-2016 10.51.55.000 AM   3570
101   4163      MA      03-Aug-2016 10.52.13.000 AM   2053
102   4163      MR      29-Aug-2016 10.23.24.000 AM   2053
103   4163      MA      11-Oct-2016 12.50.02.000 PM   5882
104   4163      MR      31-Oct-2016 01.37.28.000 PM   5882
105   4163      MA      07-Nov-2016 01.27.58.000 PM   5882
106   4163      FA      19-Apr-2017 11.46.50.000 AM   6011
107   4163      FA      19-Apr-2017 11.48.31.000 AM   6010
```

#### Legend:

```
MA = Male added to cage
MR = Male removed from cage
FA = Female added to cage
FR = Female removed from cage
```

In the table above, the first row says that on the `event_date`, a female animal (with an id of `3570`) was added to the cage for the purpose of breeding.

---

If you follow the history logs you'll get these points as *"actual mating"*:

```
female_id    male_id    event_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
3570         2053       03-Aug-2016 10.52.13.000 AM
3570         5882       11-Oct-2016 12.50.02.000 PM
3570         5882       07-Nov-2016 01.27.58.000 PM
6011         5882       19-Apr-2017 11.46.50.000 AM
6010         5882       19-Apr-2017 11.48.31.000 AM
```

However when I tried to convert my thoughts into SQL I didn't get what I wanted above.

#### SQL

```
SELECT
  be.cage_id, be.code AS base_code, be.animal_id AS base_animal, be.event_date AS base_date,
  se.code AS sub_code, se.animal_id AS sub_animal, se.event_date AS sub_date
FROM mating_history be
  LEFT JOIN mating_history se ON se.cage_id = be.cage_id
WHERE be.cage_id = 4163
  AND be.code != se.code
  AND be.code IN ('MA', 'FA')
  AND se.code IN ('MA', 'FA')
  AND be.event_date < se.event_date
ORDER BY be.event_date ASC, se.event_date ASC
```

#### Result

```
cage_id    base_code   base_animal    base_date                    sub_code    sub_animal     sub_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4163       FA          3570           03-Aug-2016 10.51.55.000 AM  MA          2053           03-Aug-2016 10.52.13.000 AM
4163       FA          3570           03-Aug-2016 10.51.55.000 AM  MA          5882           11-Oct-2016 12.50.02.000 PM
4163       FA          3570           03-Aug-2016 10.51.55.000 AM  MA          5882           07-Nov-2016 01.27.58.000 PM
4163       MA          2053           03-Aug-2016 10.52.13.000 AM  FA          6011           19-Apr-2017 11.46.50.000 AM --------> WRONG
4163       MA          2053           03-Aug-2016 10.52.13.000 AM  FA          6010           19-Apr-2017 11.48.31.000 AM --------> WRONG
4163       MA          5882           11-Oct-2016 12.50.02.000 PM  FA          6011           19-Apr-2017 11.46.50.000 AM --------> WRONG
4163       MA          5882           11-Oct-2016 12.50.02.000 PM  FA          6010           19-Apr-2017 11.48.31.000 AM --------> WRONG
4163       MA          5882           07-Nov-2016 01.27.58.000 PM  FA          6011           19-Apr-2017 11.46.50.000 AM
4163       MA          5882           07-Nov-2016 01.27.58.000 PM  FA          6010           19-Apr-2017 11.48.31.000 AM
```

---

I'm out of ideas on how to get the 5 rows that I need. How do I further filter the result out so I get just the 5 rows that I need in this case?

*Optional*: Is creating a Cartesian product even the best solution for what I'm trying to accomplish? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This will get complicated really fast. What if female 101 is in the cage for two weeks, and male 401 is added on the first day, removed two days later, then added back three days later, then removed again after a few days, and then added again? Will there be three mating events of 101 and 401 over that two-week period? It seems if 101 and 401 are both in the cage for the same two weeks, only the first day is counted (you don't have 14 mating events, one for each day); how is adding and removing 401 every few days different from that scenario?

Comment: @mathguy We consider a mating when a male and female gets paired up but not counting the days they were together. So in your question yes there will be 3 mating events for 101 and 401 **and not** 14. I haven't tried your solution and Gordon Linoff's as I just got to the office.

Comment: My solution is written with that understanding (just as you described). I didn't read Gordon's solution closely, but from his explanation he doesn't seem to consider the case when a male is added to a cage that has two females in it, resulting in two mating events.

Comment: My point about that way of counting not making sense, though, was this: If a female is in a cage from Monday through Saturday and a male is in the cage for the same period, then there is exactly one mating event. But if we take the male (or the female) out on Wednesday and put him or her back in the cage on Friday, there will be two mating events. WHY?

Comment: I understand these are your business rules, you don't make them, you just implement them - I was only saying that in my opinion the business rules themselves don't make sense. Why would the dogs mate again on Friday, but only if one of them was out of the cage for a day or two - but they wouldn't mate again on Friday if they were together in the cage for the whole week? In any case, this has nothing to do with code development to implement the requirement as it was given to you.

Comment: @mathguy Oh I see yes that is a valid question. The main purpose of the report I'm making is to list what we consider as a mating event and whether or not a litter was born because of it. So whenever a male and a female gets paired up we take that as one mating event and track whether a litter was produced.

Comment: If so, then the requirement can be clarified and the problem becomes that much more challenging and interesting.... although I am not in the breeding business so I am not sure how it really works. It would be easy to say "if a mating event for a female is counted in the query, then no other events for the same female will be counted for the next "x" months." But a mating may not result in a pup, in which case this formulation of the requirement won't work. Anyway, it's all about the business rules, not about how Oracle queries are written...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

**Setup**:

```
create table mating_history (
      id         number    primary key
    , cage_id    number    not null
    , code       char(2)   check (code in ('FA', 'FR', 'MA', 'MR'))
    , event_date timestamp not null
    , animal_id  number    not null
);

insert into mating_history
  select 100, 4163, 'FA', timestamp '2016-08-03 10:51:55', 3570 from dual union all
  select 101, 4163, 'MA', timestamp '2016-08-03 10:52:13', 2053 from dual union all
  select 102, 4163, 'MR', timestamp '2016-08-29 10:23:24', 2053 from dual union all
  select 103, 4163, 'MA', timestamp '2016-10-11 12:50:02', 5882 from dual union all
  select 104, 4163, 'MR', timestamp '2016-10-31 13:37:28', 5882 from dual union all
  select 105, 4163, 'MA', timestamp '2016-11-07 13:27:58', 5882 from dual union all
  select 106, 4163, 'FA', timestamp '2017-04-19 11:46:50', 6011 from dual union all
  select 107, 4163, 'FA', timestamp '2017-04-19 11:48:31', 6010 from dual
;

commit;
```

This is bad in several ways. There should be small "dimension" tables for cages and for animals. The animals table should show the sex (not the "code" in your current table). For now I assumed the data is as you presented it and you are not inclined to fix the data model.

**Query**:

```
with
     grouped ( cage_id, sex, event_code, event_date, animal_id, grp ) as (
       select cage_id, substr(code, 1, 1), substr(code, 2), 
              event_date, animal_id,
              row_number() over (partition by animal_id, code order by event_date) 
       from   mating_history
     ),
     pivoted as (
       select *
       from   grouped
       pivot  ( max(event_date) for event_code in ('A' as a, 'R' as r) )
     )
select   f.animal_id as female_id,
         m.animal_id as male_id,
         greatest(f.a, m.a) as event_date
from     ( select * from pivoted where sex = 'F' ) f
         join
         ( select * from pivoted where sex = 'M' ) m
         on     f.cage_id = m.cage_id
            and ( f.r >= m.a or f.r is null )
            and ( m.r >= f.a or m.r is null )
order by event_date, female_id, male_id
;
```

**Output**: (the `event_date` column uses my current `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`)

```
 FEMALE_ID   MALE_ID    EVENT_DATE                             
 ---------   -------    ------------------------------
      3570      2053    03-AUG-2016 10.52.13.000000000          
      3570      5882    11-OCT-2016 12.50.02.000000000          
      3570      5882    07-NOV-2016 13.27.58.000000000          
      6011      5882    19-APR-2017 11.46.50.000000000          
      6010      5882    19-APR-2017 11.48.31.000000000
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't modify the data model as we are using a third-party software so we have to make do with what is available.

Comment: I could confirm that this works for this scenario so I'm upvoting this solution (will accept as answer later after some more tests). Will try it out with some other scenarios and see if it breaks.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio - please make sure to test Gordon's solution as well - let him know if it works, and if it doesn't, what doesn't. Perhaps it does work and it is more efficient than mine. I don't have your data so I can't test it, but you can.

Comment: As a side-note I had to change `partition by animal_id, code order by event_date` to `partition by cage_id, animal_id, code order by event_date`. This is because extra rows were observed that looked like were coming from another cage.

Comment: @uom - Good catch! Indeed, the way I had them, the grouping was done regardless of whether the dogs were in the same cage or a different one. (I didn't catch it since I only tested on the data provided, which only had one cage_id.) The solution you found is indeed the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep track of who is in the cage . . . and assume that there is only one male and one female.  The following gets the animals in the cage for each change:

```
select mh.*,
       (case when 'MA' = lag(case when base_code in ('MA', 'MR') then base_code end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date)
             then lag(case when base_code in ('MA') then animal_id end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date)
        end) as male_animal,
       (case when 'FA' = lag(case when base_code in ('FA', 'FR') then base_code end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date)
             then lag(case when base_code in ('FA') then animal_id end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date)
        end) as female_animal,
       lead(event_date) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date) as next_event_date
from mating_history mh;
```

You want the ones where both animals are present:

```
select mh.*
from (select mh.*,
             (case when 'MA' = lag(case when base_code in ('MA', 'MR') then base_code end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date) = 'MA'
                   then lag(case when base_code in ('MA') then animal_id end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date)
              end) as male_animal,
             (case when 'FA' = lag(case when base_code in ('FA', 'FR') then base_code end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date) = 'FA'
                   then lag(case when base_code in ('FA') then animal_id end ignore nulls) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date)
              end) as female_animal,
             lead(event_date) over (partition by cage_id order by event_date) as next_event_date
      from mating_history mh
     ) mh
where male_animal is not null and female_animal is not null;
```

Comment: For both queries you provided I'm getting `ORA-00905: missing keyword`. I did have to change `base_code` to `code`. The error highlights the equal sign in this part of the queries: `over (partition by cage_id order by event_date) = 'MA'`.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio - that is easily fixed. Gordon wrote `'MA' = ... = 'MA'`, obviously that is wrong, but you can correct it by deleting the repeated `= 'MA'` at the end. Note that he did the same with `'FA' = ... = 'FA'`.